# XML data retrieval when tags are of same name using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery-sql

For the below XML:

```
<SheetData>
    <Finance>
        <value>1000</value>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Attribute>Sales</Attribute>
    </Finance>
    <Finance>
        <value>5000</value>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Attribute>Assets</Attribute>
    </Finance>
</SheetData>
```

How can I retrieve the content of Value tag based on the entry in Attribute using Sql server query.
If the attribute is assets, the value should be 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SheetData>
  <Finance>
    <value>1000</value>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Attribute>Sales</Attribute>
  </Finance>
  <Finance>
    <value>5000</value>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Attribute>Assets</Attribute>
  </Finance>
</SheetData>';

DECLARE @attr VARCHAR(100)='Assets';

SELECT @xml.value('(/SheetData/Finance[Attribute=sql:variable("@attr")]/value/text())[1]','int')
```

You read the `XPath` as follows:

Start at `SheetData` and navigate down to `Finance`. Search for the node, where the `<Attribute>` is like the given variable and read the `value`'s text from there.

### UPDATE

Your second example (in comment) adds one more nesting level `Component`:

```
declare @xml xml=
'<SheetData>
  <Finance>
    <value>1000</value>
    <GeoCurr>
      <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </GeoCurr>
    <Component>
      <Attribute>Sales</Attribute>
    </Component>
  </Finance>
  <Finance>
    <value>5000</value>
    <GeoCurr>
      <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </GeoCurr>
    <Component>
      <Attribute>Assets</Attribute>
    </Component>
  </Finance>
</SheetData>';

DECLARE @attr VARCHAR(100)='Assets';

SELECT @xml.value('(/SheetData/Finance[Component/Attribute=sql:variable("@attr")]/value/text())[1]','int')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But what if xml is as below:               <SheetData>
  <Finance>
    <value>1000</value>
    <GeoCurr>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
     </GeoCurr>
      <Component>
    <Attribute>Sales</Attribute>
    </Component>
  </Finance>
  <Finance>
    <value>5000</value>
    <GeoCurr>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </GeoCurr>
    <Component>
    <Attribute>Assets</Attribute>
    </Component>
  </Finance>
</SheetData>

Comment: @Kapil See my update and please avoid chameleon questions!